# Why is the dual of $L^\infty$ not $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis

From the Riesz representation theorem, we know that the dual  of $L^p$ is isomorphic to $L^q$ for $1<p<\infty$, where $q$ is the conjugate index of $q$  (i.e. $1/p+1/q=1$). And if the measure space $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite, then the dual of $L^1$ is isomrophic to $L^\infty$. But the dual of $L^\infty$ is subtler, The dual $L^\infty$ is  isomorphic to the space of signed finitely additive measures on $X$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, which is named as [ba space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_space). Why is the dual of $L^\infty$ is not $L^1$? We can simply show that $(L^\infty)^*\neq L^1$, but I want to know why the argument used in   $1\leq p<\infty$ doesn't work in  $p=\infty$.

Chasing through the proof of the Riesz representation theorem, I notice that the dominated convergence theorem fails in the case $p=\infty$, that is if $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of measurable function dominated by a non-negative function $g\in L^p$  and $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to a limit $f$, then we have $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\to \|f\|_{L^p}$ as $n\to\infty$ if $1\leq p<\infty$. But this is not true if $p=\infty$. Indeed, if we take $f_n=1_{[n,n+1]}$, clearly, we have $f_n\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}$) and $|f_n|\leq 1$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^\infty}\neq \|f\|_{L^\infty}$ since the LHS is $1$ and the RHS is $0$. Is this the reason?

Comment: Yes.  In the proof, we cannot show the "measure" we get is countably additive.  So Riesz representation cannot be applied.

Comment: @GEdgar It seems that the problem comes from the definition of $L^\infty$ norm, it is not defined by integral.

Comment: @GEdgar: You mean the Radon Nikodym theorem?